# Execution failed for task ':kaptGenerateStubsKotlin' for `gradle build` command

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have kotlin service and I need use `kotlinter` for it. When I try to run the `gradle build` command I get such error. But I already have `spring-boot-dependencies` in my file's dependency.

Can you please tell me what could be my mistake?  I've been trying to figure it out for hours now, but it still doesn't work.

```
Execution failed for task ':kaptGenerateStubsKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':kaptGenerateStubsKotlin'
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration5'.
      > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
        Searched in the following locations:
          - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
          - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-dependencies-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

`build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.10"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.7.10"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.13.RELEASE"
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.21.0"
    id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "3.0.2"
}

kotlinter {
    disabledRules = arrayOf("import-ordering")
}

group = "com.site"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // STARTERS
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongock-spring-v5:4.1.14")
    implementation("com.github.cloudyrock.mongock:mongodb-springdata-v3-driver:4.1.14")

    // LIBS
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:2.1.23")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")

    // PROCESSORS
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.2.Final")

    // LINTER
    detektPlugins("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:1.21.0")

    // TESTS
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("de.bwaldvogel:mongo-java-server:1.39.0")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's magic, but I replaced `plugins` in `build.gradle.kts` with the code below and it helped.

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.7.10"

    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion

    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version "1.21.0"
    id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "3.0.2"
}
```

If someone can explain in a little more detail the essence of the problem and why my solution helped, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You basically downgraded the SpringBoot from `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to `2.6.6`. SpringBoot 3 is not officially released yet even though the snapshots are available. If you want to try SB3 snapshots you need to add proper spring boot repositories. File `settings.gradle.kts`:
```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
}
rootProject.name = "demo"
```
Try yourself at [https://start.spring.io/](https://start.spring.io/).